# Annotate queryset with a boolean from ManyToMany relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Lets say I have a `Book` model like this:

```
class Book(models.Model)
    title = models.Charfield(...)
    likes = models.ManyToMany(User, related_name="books_liked")
```

I need to annotate a queryset with a `is_liked` field for the current logged user.

I have this in the view, but it's not working:

```
    user = self.request.user
    qs = Book.objects.all().annotate(is_liked=Exists(user.books_liked.all()))
    return qs
```

so I can use something like this in the template

```
{% for book in books %}
    {% if book.is_liked %}
      ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm checking this docs section, but I'm not too sure how to proceed or if is the correct way.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `is_liked` to be used as `if book.is_liked` ?

Comment: For now on templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I have to create a explicit Like model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

and remove the `ManyToMany` relation on `Book`

then in the view this:

```
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    user_likes = Like.objects.filter(
        book=OuterRef("pk"),
        user=self.request.user
    )
    return Book.objects.annotate(
        is_liked=Exists(user_likes)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but. It's possible to solve that by using SQL logic without an explicit model. Just use CASE WHEN.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

user_id = self.request.user.id
qs = Book.objects.annotate(is_liked=Case(
    When(likes__id=user_id, then=Value(True)),
    default=False
)
```

The rest works fine.

Documentation: [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

Well this caused some weird behaviour when more than 1 user likes the same book. So, using Q instead proved to be more useful. However, this throws error in case user isn't logged in. So with a try except block it worked. Here is the fix:

```
from django.db.models import Q

try:
    liked_id = self.request.user.books_liked.values("id")
except AttributeError:
    qs = Book.objects.all()
else:
    qs = Book.objects.annotate(is_liked=Q(id__in=liked_id))
```